# What is the problem with this contract?

Tags: solidity

whenever I am trying to use transferFrom function after using the approve function it is showing me an error

code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract tranfer{
    function approve(address tokenadd, uint amount) public {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenadd);
        token.approve(address(this),amount);
    }
    function transfer(address tokenadd,address recipient, uint amount ) public {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenadd);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender,recipient, amount);
    }
}
```

error: insufficient allowance

Answer (score 0):

The approve method takes three parameters: owner, spender, amount.

When you call the approve method within your contract function "approve", The ERC20 token uses your contract as the "owner" parameter.

So to send tokens from one user to another user through your contract you have to send the approve function directly from the ERC20 Token you are trying to send and you will have to approve this contract to spend your tokens.